# php Script to delete all files in directory on server

Tags: php, delete-file

I need to delete the contents of plugin cache folder every 20 mins. I have a job planner (task planner) on my hosting. The problem is, that I need a php script, which will order to delete all the files within specified directory.

Please, help me with such one.

Thank You in advance to you all, who will answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try something like this and let us know if any error/warning.
This is a recursive function to delete all files and sub-directory within a directory.

```
<?php
function delete_directory($dirname) {
     if (is_dir($dirname))
         $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
     if (!$dir_handle)
          return false;
     while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
           if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
                     unlink($dirname."/".$file);
                else
                     delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);
           }
     }
     closedir($dir_handle);
     rmdir($dirname);
     return true;
}
?>
```

For details see [Here](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php-files-delete.php)